# What are resonant tori?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, resonance, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

What is the definition of a resonant/invariant torus (in the phase space of a Hamiltonian system)? Are there non-resonant tori?

Answer (score 4):

2D invariant tori in Hamiltonian phase spaces are characterized by two frequencies, one for each dimension: when these frequencies are commensurate ($f_1/f_2$ is rational), curves over these tori close onto themselves and are therefore *periodic* - these are **resonant tori**; when the frequencies are not commensurate, the corresponding trajectories are not closed, they are *quasi-periodic* - and they fill **non-resonant tori**.

The nomenclature is based on the effect a perturbation has over the Hamiltonian: the resonant tori are more readily affected by the perturbation, through a resonance mechanism, while the non-resonant tori are affected through second-order, nonlinear mechanisms.

You can check [Arnold's book](https://books.google.de/books?id=UOQlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA402&lpg=PA402&dq=resonant%20tori&source=bl&ots=Qoo8UNVImg&sig=n1oto5k48WqVCq_1yRyVqS4CXO4&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=resonant%20tori&f=false) to learn more about that.

Comment: wouldn’t that be $4D$ if you have two angle (and thus two action) variables?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The phase space is 4D, but the tori are 2D.